# Profiles Not Supported Anymore in IPython Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Current version of IPython-notebook doesn't support profiles. IPython works perfectly fine: `ipython --profile test`. But `ipython notebook --profile test` fails with the following output:

```
Examples
--------

    ipython notebook                       # start the notebook
    ipython notebook --profile=sympy       # use the sympy profile
    ipython notebook --certfile=mycert.pem # use SSL/TLS certificate

[C 14:04:28.232 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 14:04:28.232 NotebookApp] Unrecognized flag: '--profile'
```

It is still in the examples, but doesn't really work. Is there a way to use profile with IPython-notebook?

Below is my `pip freeze`:

```
appnope==0.1.0
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
certifi==2015.11.20.1
decorator==4.0.6
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipykernel==4.2.1
ipython==4.0.1
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter-client==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.0.6
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7.1
nbconvert==4.1.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.0.6
path.py==8.1.2
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.5
ptyprocess==0.5
Pygments==2.0.2
pyzmq==15.1.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
terminado==0.5
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.0.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

Comment: Since you're using ipython 4.0, it means behind the scenes you're using Jupyter for the notebooks. Jupyter doesn't support ipython profiles anymore, so you have to [read about migrating configurations from ipython to jupyter](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html). You'd be most interested in the **Profiles** section.

Answer (score -1):

As @birryree mentioned in comments IPython 4.0 is now Jupyter. [The docs with migration](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html#profiles) are not really clear to me. So the easiest solution is to install IPython 3, which still supports profiles:

```
pip install ipython[notebook]==3.2.3
```